# User data command does not execute on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2

I added this command to "user data" input box so that jupyter notebook would start when I purchase a new instance.

```
/root/miniforge3/bin/jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='passwd' --notebook-dir=/tmp/ --ip='0.0.0.0' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root
```

All the required softwares are already installed in the IAM that I have selected. The problem is that this line is not executed on start up and I need to log-in and run it myself. Is this the right way to automate python notebook? Is there error log saved somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User data is nothing but shell-scripts. It should start with shebang.

```
#!/bin/bash
```